# Having trouble with equals/not equals using array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on an Address Book homework assignment for Java, using arrays. I am stuck on how to make sure someone isn't in the address book before adding them, and making sure they are in the address book in order to delete them. I have three files; hopefully I'll copy the code into here correctly. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong are most appreciated.

This is the AddressBook class:

```
package addressbook;

public class AddressBook
{

    // declaring variable addressBook as reference
    // to an array of Person objects
    Person[] addressBook;

    // using a static field to keep track of 
    // the number of person objects
    public static int people = 0;

    // allocate memory for the array field in a constructor
    public AddressBook()
    {
        addressBook = new Person[2];
    }

    //Method to add a person object to the addressBook       
    public void AddPerson(Person person)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < people; i++)
        {
            if (addressBook[i] != person)
            {
                // check to see if the number of person objects
                // is fewer than the number of spaces in the array
                if (people < addressBook.length)
                {
                    // add new person to array at the position
                    //  specified by variable people (starting with 0)
                    addressBook[people] = person;
                } // if there are too many person objects
                // to fit in the address book
                else
                {
                    // declare a temp array twice the length of address book
                    Person[] temp = new Person[addressBook.length * 2];
                    for (int j = 0; j < addressBook.length; j++) // put the references from the old address book into temp
                    {
                        temp[j] = addressBook[j];
                    }
                    //add the new person object into temp
                    temp[people] = person;
                    // copy the reference to temp into address book
                    addressBook = temp;
                }
                // increase person object count (since you just added a person)
                people++;
                // print to the console to see if method is working
                System.out.println("people = " + people + "\n"
                        + "addressBook.Length = " + addressBook.length);
            }
        }
    }
    // Method to search for a person by name.
    // Searches both first and last names
    // and puts the results into an array.

    public Person[] searchName(String name)
    {
        Person[] searchResults = new Person[addressBook.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < people; i++)
        {
            if ((addressBook[i].firstName.equals(name))
                    || (addressBook[i].lastName.equals(name)))
            {
                searchResults[i] = addressBook[i];
            }
        }
        return searchResults;
    }

    // Method to search for a person by ID number.
    // Puts the results into an array.
    public Person[] searchID(int id)
    {
        Person[] resultsList = new Person[addressBook.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < people; i++)
        {
            if (addressBook[i].idNumber == id)
            {
                resultsList[i] = addressBook[i];
            }
        }
        return resultsList;
    }

    //Method to remove a person object from the addressBook
    public void removePerson(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < people; i++) // Search by ID number.
        {
            if (addressBook[i].idNumber == id)
            {
                // copy the ref to the last person object in array
                // into the index location of the person object being removed
                addressBook[i] = addressBook[people - 1];
                // set the ref of the (formerly) last person object to null
                addressBook[people - 1] = null;
                // decrease person object count (since you just removed a person) 
                people--;
            }
        }
        // If your count of people is 25% or less than the 
        // length of your address book
        if (people <= (addressBook.length / 4))
        {
            // declare a temp array half the length of address book
            Person[] temp = new Person[addressBook.length / 2];
            for (int j = 0; j < people; j++) // put the references from the old address book into temp
            {
                temp[j] = addressBook[j];
            }
            // copy the reference to temp into address book
            addressBook = temp;
        }
        // print to the console to see if method is working
        System.out.println("Count= " + people + "\n"
                + "addressBook.Length= " + addressBook.length);
    }

    // Prints the array to the console
    public void PrintAddressBook()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < addressBook.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(addressBook[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Person class:

```
package addressbook;

public class Person
{
    public String firstName, lastName;
    public int idNumber = 0;
    public static int nextIdNumber;

    public Person(String fn, String ln)
    {
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
        nextIdNumber++;
        idNumber = nextIdNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName)
    {
        firstName = newFirstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String newLastName)
    {
        lastName = newLastName;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("First name: " + firstName + "\n"
                + "Last name: " + lastName + "\n"
                + "Full name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\n"
                + "ID number: " + idNumber);
    }

    public void printInformation()
    {
        System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName + ", " + idNumber);
    }
}
```

And this is the AddressBookTester:

```
package addressbook;

public class AddressBookTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();

        System.out.println("-----Testing a Person Constructor-----");
        System.out.println("--------using ToString Method--------\n");
        Person person1 = new Person("Helen", "Mirren");
        System.out.println(person1);
        System.out.println();

        Person person2 = new Person("Helen", "Thomas");
        System.out.println(person2);
        Person person3 = new Person("Thomas", "Wolfe");
        System.out.println(person3);
        Person person4 = new Person("Robert", "Redford");
        System.out.println(person4);
        Person person5 = new Person("Robbie", "Robertson");
        System.out.println(person5);

        System.out.println("--Testing Add Person Method--");
        addressBook.AddPerson(person1);
        addressBook.AddPerson(person2);
        addressBook.AddPerson(person3);
        addressBook.AddPerson(person4);
        addressBook.AddPerson(person5);
        addressBook.PrintAddressBook();

        System.out.println("----Testing Search by Name Method------");
        //create return Person object array for searchName function
        Person[] searchList = addressBook.searchName("Helen");
        for (int i = 0; i < searchList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(searchList[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("----Testing Search by ID Method------");
        Person[] results = addressBook.searchID(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(results[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("----Testing Remove Person Method------");
        addressBook.removePerson(4);
        addressBook.removePerson(3);
        addressBook.removePerson(2);
        addressBook.PrintAddressBook();
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get:

```
/*run:
-----Testing a Person Constructor-----
--------using ToString Method--------

First name: Helen
Last name: Mirren
Full name: Helen Mirren
ID number: 1

First name: Helen
Last name: Thomas
Full name: Helen Thomas
ID number: 2
First name: Thomas
Last name: Wolfe
Full name: Thomas Wolfe
ID number: 3
First name: Robert
Last name: Redford
Full name: Robert Redford
ID number: 4
First name: Robbie
Last name: Robertson
Full name: Robbie Robertson
ID number: 5
--Testing Add Person Method--
null
null
----Testing Search by Name Method------
null
null
----Testing Search by ID Method------
null
null
----Testing Remove Person Method------
Count= 0
addressBook.Length= 1
Count= 0
addressBook.Length= 0
Count= 0
addressBook.Length= 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
*/
```

Thanks for any ideas as to how to fix this code. I am very new to coding, obviously...

Comment: Try looking up how to compare objects in Java. (specifically using equals/hashcode)

Comment: Can't you just use a `Set<Person>` and have a coffee?

Comment: @Mena I don't think he is allowed to use Set. It's a homework..

Comment: @Lorien what Kurt said is that you cannot do this in Java:  if (addressBook[i] != person), check how to compare 2 objects!

Comment: @KurtDuBois, thank you for your suggestion. Is it because addressBook[i] contains the memory address, not the actual variable? We haven't studied hashcode yet.

Comment: Think about what it means to say that a person is already in the address book.  Do you mean that the exact same `Person` object is in the array?  Or any `Person` object with the same id number?  Or any `Person` object with the same first name and last name?  Once you have it clear in your mind what you want, coding it will be easier.

Comment: @Alboz I think you are correct; I don't even know what Set is, yet. I am having trouble thinking of how to compare what is in addressBook[i] with person. I will keep studying equals, but I can't use hashcode.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I am unfortunately confused, as I feel like I am trying to say all of those things. Each Person object has a unique ID number, so ideally that is what I should be searching for. I feel like my issue is, how to find out if a Person object with the same ID is already in the addressBook array.

Comment: So it seems to me that you want to replace `if (addressBook[i] != person)` with something like `if (addressBook[i].getIdNumber() != person.getIdNumber())` if that's the thing  you want to check.  You will, of course, have to write a `getIdNumber()` method in the `Person` class.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWallace! I will see if I can figure out how to write a getIdNumber() method in the Person class and incorporate it into the AddressBook class. (And clearly, I should also learn how to mark up my comment code here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't thoroughly read your code right now, but I'll try and give a few hints on some points I observed.

No. 1:

In your `searchX()` methods you return an array of `Person` which is exactly the size of the address book. Within the methods you loop over the addressbook (hint use foreach instead of looping by index) and then call `searchResults[i] = addressBook[i];`. This might result in a lot of null entries all over the result array.

You might want to have a different index for `searchResults` instead and increment that only when you add an entry. That way all the null entries are at the end of the array and you can easily make a copy of that array and leave out the empty part at the end.

No. 2:

In general, if you're allowed to use collections like `List`, `Set` etc. use those instead of arrays.

No. 3:

Don't compare objects with == or != like in `if( addressBook[i] != person)` since you could create two objects with the same data and you'd not see that they're equal due to == comparing object indentity instead of equality.

No. 4:

You're not getting the printed statemend when calling `addPerson()` which should indicate there's something wrong.

Try and debug your code and you should see that `for (int i = 0; i < people; i++)` will result in no iteration since `people` initially is 0 and thus `i < 0` is never satisfied. Hence nothing gets added to your array.

**I think here's the real problem:**

Your `addPerson` method has a wrong structure. Besides the `i < 0` problem mentioned above, you're adding each new  person multiple times since you don't terminate the loops but add the person whenever `addressBook[i] != person` which would be true for every entry in the array in the case of a new person.

Try and change that to something like the following pseudo code:

```
boolean personInArray = searchById( person.getId() );

if( !personInArray ) {
  if( people == addressBook.length) {
    //resize the array, since it is full and the person should be added 
  }

  //add the person
  addressBook[people] = person;
  people++;
}
```

No. 5:

As a side note, try to stick to the Java code conventions, e.g. method names always start with a lower case character, i.e. `addPerson` instead of `AddPerson`. Although this more a matter of style it will help you and others to debug and understand your code.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas! These are all excellent points. The frustrating thing is, I successfully completed this very same assignment in C# just last week, so I really didn't think I would have to change so much. And unfortunately I'm not allow to use List or Set. I will take your advice and see if I can improve my code.

Comment: Thank you for your edited advice @Thomas; I will have to take a closer look at it tomorrow (it's very late here). And also thank you for the note about Java code conventions. Honestly, I started with my C# code and was editing it, so I missed some case conventions that my IDE didn't catch.

Comment: Both Thomas and @Sebastian Axelsen gave helpful answers; since I can only choose one, I'm going with Thomas, because his was first, and because at least I understood the part of his answer having to do with Java code naming conventions. I'm still working on the equals conundrum. I thought a classmate had solved it, but when I tested his code, a lot of it doesn't work, so at least I'm not alone... I look forward to learning List and Set, someday!

Comment: @Lorien have a look at No 4 which I think is the core of your problem. Besides that, you should definitely have a look into lists and sets, which are not too difficult to understand: lists provide an ordering and can grow when needed, sets can grow as well but don't always provide an order (unless you use special sets like `TreeSet` or `LinkedHashSet`) but the most useful part is that sets don't allow duplicates. To get things right, you need to correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` though, so have a look at those as well.

Comment: Thomas, thank you again! This is all very useful. We have another assignment due soon for which we get to use lists, so at least I'll get to try those out very soon.
You were correct, the boolean did help. My professor helped me with the last part; I had the boolean backwords. This ended up working:
`boolean isInBook = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < people; i++)
        {
            if (addressBook[i] == person)
            {
                isInBook = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isInBook)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried, but I can't figure out how to get the code to format in a comment. I'll keep looking for instructions for that... Anyway, the boolean was the missing piece. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lorien you're welcome :) Don't bother too much with formatting code in comments, AFAIK it's not very well supported - and IMHO comments are not the best location for code anyways, you can always make an addition/update to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a very clear problem firstly:

You start by initializing the `person` count keeper to 0, and then in your `AddPerson()` method you initiate your loop to perform:

```
for(int i=0;i<person;i++){
...
}
```

since `person = 0`, it won't even enter the loop, because 0 is not less than 0.

Secondly, you are performing an `==` comparison on objects, which is bound to go wrong. Here's why:

`==` and `!=` are reference comparisons, i.e. `==` will only return true if the two objects being compared are referencing the same object in memory.

Instead, you should use the `.equals(...)` function, but since your `Person` class does not extend anything, this will default to the `Object.equals()` superclass method, which is equivalent to the above.

Hence the correct way to go about the comparison, is to override the `equals()` method for the `Person` class such that it returns `true` if e.g. the first and last name are the same, or whichever your criteria may be. At the same time, you should also make sure to override the `hashCode()` method to honor the contract between those two methods. You can read more about this e.g. here: 
http://javarevisited.blogspot.dk/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html

Comment: Thank you, @Sebastian Axelsen! You are right, that for loop shouldn't even have been there. I think it was left in there from too many edits too late at night, when I was trying a variety of things. Thank you for catching that!
As to the equals method problems, your answer does give me one more perspective on the issue, but we haven't studied anything about hashCode(), so I will probably have to go another way to solve this issue with the equals. But I very much appreciate your time on this. I wish I had enough rep to upvote things; as soon as I do I will upvote this answer!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Your question is quite common and definitely amongst java "must-knows". For the assignment, overriding the hashCode() method probably isn't necessary, but for future reference it is considered good practice to do so, since the equals() and hashCode() methods should follow each other.